# Native Windows Function IsTpmReady throws "too many posts were made to a semaphore" error

Tags: windows, go, system-calls

I'm attempting to call the TpmIsReady function from the TpmCoreProvisioning.dll included on Windows.  I don't notice anything glaringly wrong with the code, but the error is thrown regardless.

This is what I have:

```
package windows

import (
    "errors"
    "log"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

var (
    TPMDLL   = syscall.NewLazyDLL("TpmCoreProvisioning.dll")
    TpmReady = TPMDLL.NewProc("TpmIsReady")
)

func IsTpmReady() (bool, error) {
    var enabled byte
    ptr := (uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(&enabled))
    _, _, err := TpmReady.Call(ptr)
    if errors.Is(err, syscall.Errno(0)) {
        return enabled == 1, nil
    }
    if DEBUG {
        log.Printf("IsTpmReady: %v", err)
    }
    return false, err
}
```

Am I using something incorrectly, or not freeing resources?

Comment: Are you using an antivirus software? Try to disable it to see if that does anything. Also do your run your program as an Administrator? https://windowsreport.com/too-many-posts-semaphore/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is not really my area of expertise as @Eelco has mentioned most of the time it should be related to your antivirus.
You can proceed through this checklist:

1. Disable any anti-virus you have running includes windows defender
2. Run it as administrator(I assume you would have tried this already)
3. Check if you are on the latest version of windows

---

If it still doesn't work try performing a clean boot by

1. Press windows + R and type "msconfig"
2. It should open "system configuration" from which you have to navigate to the "services tab" and check "Hide all Microsoft services box" and press the disable button
3. Navigate to the startup tab and disable all the programs in the same fashion then click apply after closing the task manager windows inside the tab
4. Proceed to restart your machine and run the program again

---

If it still doesn't work perhaps restart your machine in safe mode (with networking as it's easier to search something in case needed) and try again.

---

IF IT STILL DOESN'T WORK: at this point I don't know what else works. But you could try running it on another machine and see if the error persists. You can reset your machine but it would be rather inconvenient. Check if you have any programs that might conflict or extensions.

Comment: I'm sorry if it's hard to follow through I've just erratically written this in a short time-frame...

Comment: I went ahead and accepted this answer as I can't seem to make it work on my machine, though the issue does not persist on others.  The scope of this question does not include really figuring out why it doesn't work on my machine.